# Recreate a stream after navigation back on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

Scenario: I create a firebase snapshot stream and do some calculations from that data before showing this finalized data on a widget/page. User clicks on items on this widget and navigates to a new page. (the work done on this page affects the stream on the first page). After the user navigates back using the back button, I want to create a new stream and do the calculation again to show the correct data.

Question: how do I do this without memory leaks. I mean how do I track navigation back and dispose the previous stream and create a new stream? At the moment I get *Badstate* exceptions if I try to recreate streamcontroller or stream.

Code:

**Stream**

```
Future<Stream> getData() async {
  Stream stream1 = _getReceiverStream();
  Stream stream2 = _getSenderStream();
  return StreamGroup.merge([stream1, stream2]).asBroadcastStream();
}
```

**Stream controller**

```
@override
void initState() {
  streamController = StreamController();
  streamController.stream.listen((p) => readData(p));
  setupData();
}


setupData() async {
  Stream<dynamic> stream = await service.getData();
  stream.pipe(streamController);
}
```

Comment: Is the code shown above your actual code? If not, please show us your actual code and the errors you are receiving. I am having a hard time understanding your problem exactly. Streams can be tricky and I would like to understand more to try to help you.

Comment: thanks, guys, I figured it out. I had to cancel the stream subscription and recreate the controller and the stream after closing them. Everything worked fine after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign StreamSubscription to a global variable. Then cancel it first before disposing streamController. To track the user navigation back to the page implement didPopNext RoutAware method. There dispose and recreate the stream and controller.

See the code below.

```
streamController = StreamController();
subscription = streamController.stream.listen((p) => readData(p));

 @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    await unregisterFromDataStream();
  }

  Future<void> unregisterFromDataStream() async {
    if (subscription != null) {
      subscription.cancel();
    }
    if (streamController != null) {
      await streamController.close();
      streamController = null;
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() async {
    await unregisterFromDataStream();
    setupController();
    setupDataStream();

  }
```